# Какая структура БД будет лучше в таком случае?

Tags: node.js, база-данных, mongodb, mongoose

Мне нужно сделать такую БД, где у каждого зарегистрированного пользователя есть большое количество слов, которые принадлежат именно ему и их перевод. Можно сказать БД для флешкарточек. Но еще у каждого слова есть свои параметры, которые тоже нужно зарегистрировать, такие как дата добавления этого слова, существительно, глагол или наречие ли оно, так же прогресс этого слова(сколько раз человек правильно выбрал перевод данного слова в процессе практики) Так вот, какая структура будет наиболее эффективной, наиболее удобной по вашему мнению?

Можно ли в mongodb сделать такую структуру из основного массива, в котором есть объекты(зарегистрированные пользователи), а в них помимо какие-то параметров, присущих данному пользователю, также находится массив со всеми словами, а в словах уже содержатся данные параметры слова(перевод, дата добавления, его вид и прогресс) Вот что-то наподобие этого...

```
[
  {
    nickname: "",
    password: "",
    words: [
             {
               word: "",
               translation: "",
               dataAdded: "",
               type: "",
               progress: 1-10
             },
             {
               word: "",
               translation: "",
               dataAdded: "",
               type: "",
               progress: 1-10
             }
           ]
  }
]
```

Или лучше само слово вынести за объект и уже этому слову присваивать все параметры

Comment: я бы сделал так: чтобы слова не повторялись - добавил их в отдельную коллекцию. А в юзере сделал объект с полями `{ word: ObjectId(...), info: {} }`, где `info` - доп инфа для конкретного слова у конкретного юзера

Comment: @entithat Как вариант, спасибо)

Comment: Где-то кто-то когда-то сказал, что надо избегать моментов, когда придется делать лукапы (populate), но и чтобы не было повтора данных. На сайте монго есть несколько уроков как правильно организовать это дело

Comment: @entithat о, отлично, нужно чекнуть